# Creating random images at random position in corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am using the following code in corona to create a random images at random position
each time i run my code, but when i run the code i get all the random selected
images on the same position on the screen

Here is my code please give suggestion.. thanks in advance

---- in  the create scene this code is places

```
letterHolder = {} 
numOfImages = 10 

for i=1,numOfImages do
   letterHolder[i] = display.newImageRect("images/myImage.png", 20, 20) 
   letterHolder[i].x = math.random(0, display.contentWidth) 
   letterHolder[i].y = math.random(0, display.contentHeight) 
end
```

Comment: I tried your code and it's seems ok, they random in different locations, can you specify your problem more?

Comment: Is this the whole code you pasted? I've had similar issues when I was messing with randomseed. The problem with randomseed is that for the same seed you will get the same set of random numbers. Anyway.. if this is the whole thing try to add math.randomseed(os.time()) before your for loop. Make sure you don't call this code more often than once per second!

Answer (score 0):

Just try the following method. This may help you:

```
local letterHolder = {}
local numOfImages = 10
local xPosArray = {}
local yPosArray = {}
local randX,randY = 0,0
local xExists,yExists = 0,0



local function positionImages(i)
  randX = math.random(display.contentWidth)
  randY = math.random(display.contentHeight)

  if(i==1)then
    xPosArray[i] = randX
    yPosArray[i] = randY
  else
    xExists = table.indexOf( xPosArray, randX )
    yExists = table.indexOf( yPosArray, randY )
    if(xExists~=nil and yExists~=nil and xExists==yExists)then
      print("Place already occuped")
      positionImages(i)
    else
      print("Can place here")
      xPosArray[i] = randX
      yPosArray[i] = randY
    end
  end
end

for i=1,numOfImages do
  letterHolder[i] = display.newImageRect("images/myImage.png", 20, 20)
  positionImages(i)
end
```